# How to get the content of a Resource Fork?

Tags: terminal, hfs+, resources

I want to get the stored resource fork. In PHP, I'm trying to:

`system('DeRez' . $_icon . ' | perl -ne \'m|/\* (.*) \*/| && print $1; END {print "\n"}\', $content);`

which in Terminal really returns the content of the icon. However, creating an image from it using `imagecreatefromstring` returns an error.

So, there's a command-line voodoo that outputs the raw data of the resource fork (in my case, the folder icon)?

Answer (score 1):

The icon encoded within [the resource fork](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/macosx.html) is not in a format PHP's [imagecreatefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) can understand.

PHP's `imagecreatefromstring` requires:

- JPEG
- PNG
- GIF
- WBMP
- GD2

### Use sips

Investigate the Mac OS X command [sips](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) for working with icons on the command line. See [Manipulate Mac OS X file icons from Automator or command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/133784/manipulate-mac-os-x-file-icons-from-automator-or-command-line) for examples.

### DeRez

The `DeRez` command will output the raw resource fork data. The [manual for DeRez](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/DeRez.1.html) provides options for filtering the output data and requesting specific encoding; be aware that the encoding options are limited to how the hexadecimal is escaped. Rather than allowing for graphic format conversion.